# Swift Mailer Dynamic Text Attachement

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I'm trying to attach a string as a plain text file to the swift mailer message as explained in the [doc](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-dynamic-content):

```
$debug_data = 'Exception: ' . $e_message . PHP_EOL;
$debug_data .= $file . ': ' . $line . PHP_EOL;
$debug_data .= $trace;

$attach = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($debug_data, 'debug.txt', 'text/plain');

$message->attach($attach);
```

but this gives me this error:

```
Error in exception handler: fopen(Content-Type: text/plain; name=debug.txt Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=debug.txt 1ay9wdWJsaWMvaW5kZXgucGhwKDQ5KTog SWxsdW1pbmF0ZVxGb3VuZGF0aW9uXEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uLT5ydW4oKQojMTMge21haW59): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php:138
```

any idea?!

Comment: It tells you... `No such file or directory in /vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php:138`

Comment: @SeanWM it's meaningless because I don't have a file, I'm making the attachment on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use it in Laravel that has a `attachData` method which does'n call `fopen`. You can use it like below code

`$message->attachData($debug_data, 'debug.txt');`

Answer (score 1):

Both answers above are not compatible with Symfony 4.0.

For Symfony 4.0:

```
$attachment = new Swift_Attachment($debug_data, 'debug.txt', 'text/plain');
$message->attach($attachment);
```

// I post it here, because it's top google result for 'swiftmailer attachment from string'

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance()
  ->setFilename('debug.txt')
  ->setContentType('text/plain')
  ->setBody($debug_data);
```